# Customize String serialization with hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE with Hibernate 5.0.11.

I have an Entity on which I have a field that I must persist depending on another field. Let's say the entity it's like this:

```
package com.forty2apps.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.Builder;

@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "max_power")
public class MaxPower implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "problematic_field")
    private String problematic_field;

    @Column(name = "charset", nullable = false)
    private String charset;

}
```

I have to write the problematic_field as a byte_array to bypass table encoding. My first try was to using a converter, using the annotation `@Convert(converter = EncodedUtf8ByteArray.class)` on `problematic_field` and the following class:

```
package com.forty2apps.entity;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class EncodedUtf8ByteArray implements AttributeConverter<String, byte[]> {
    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] valueOnDb) {
        try {
            return new String(valueOnDb, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but it's too rigid. I need to create a converter that makes use of the field charset (in the best scenario... there are more complex business logics that may come into play).

So I tried defining my own EnhancedUserType, hoping that there would be enough informations about the entity, but SessionImplementor doesn't seem has helpful as I hoped:

```
package com.forty2apps.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType;

public class VogonStringUserType implements EnhancedUserType, Serializable {
    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Object value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toXMLString(Object value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromXMLString(String xmlValue) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.LONGVARBINARY};
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return false;//TODO
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        return "moVediamo";
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws
            HibernateException, SQLException {
        try {
            StandardBasicTypes.BINARY.nullSafeSet(st, ((String)value).getBytes("UTF-8"), index, session);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable)value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

Is there really no way to do this? 
To be clear, what I want to do is to get rid of the hardcoded `"UTF-8"` String and use the value in the charset field; also, I'd like to access the whole instance of the entity that hibernate is about to persist/read.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the design really questionable. I would rather use the same encoding, always. But anyway, why not just use OO and encapsulation:

```
@Embeddable
public class EncodedString {

    @Column(name = "problematic_field")
    private byte[] array;

    @Column(name = "charset", nullable = false)
    private String charset;

    @Transient
    private String value;

    private EncodedString() {
        // for Hibernate
    }

    public EncodedString(String value, String charset) {
        this.charset = charset;
        this.array = value == null ? null : value.getBytes(charset);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (value == null && array != null) {
            value = new String(array, charset);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public String getCharset() {
        return charset;
    }
}
```

Comment: I find the design questionable too, but I have to make a java library that works like a legacy php application, that writes everything in a table where the charset on the table is fixed but the application writes and reads it using bytes on another charset. Anyway, I wasn't able to use your solution (I had to had setters, and hibernate was complaining about circular dependancies) but your idea of using OO and encapsulation helped me find the solution, using something similar to what you posted in the main entity. Thank you very much.